# can wifi owner see .pdf file i've opened through browser?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

i know that they could see websites, traffic usage, etc using certain application. but what i wanted to ask is, if i opened a .pdf file using browser, will they be able to see it too? it appears on my browsing history so does that means it appears on theirs too?? if i remove it from my history, that doesn't mean it will be removed from theirs right?

the security type of their network is WPA2-Personal and i'm using chrome if thats relevant.

the .pdf i opened is a document on my pc which i opened through browser so the link is something like `file:///D:/New%20folder/as/New%20folder%20(8)/asdsd.pdf`. so does this still means they know it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on there do you get it. If it is .pdf, saved locally, nobody can see it (unless they have access to your pc). If you are viewing it directly from a website, it depends on type of connection: HTTP is totally unsafe, so your file can be seen by WiFi owner, but HTTPS (mostly) makes it safe.

Answer (score 0):

No, the WiFi provider cannot see the file.  The `file://` protocol accesses a file system available to your operating system.  If the PDF is stored *locally* on your computer, the file never gets transferred over the network.  Additionally, they will not see a DNS request, as the file is stored locally. They have no access to your browsing history, so you are safe in that regard.

However, the above could be rendered false in unlikely scenarios, but that would involve some strange network configurations on your end.  Other issues that could affect this are browser plugins, as well as third party programs you installed on your PC.  Simply put, do not install software on your computer you do not trust implicitly.

Comment: Why the downvote here? It's a valid answer.

Answer (score -1):

If the site **did not use https**, the owner of the wifi will see every byte you transmit, including the pdf file.

If the whole site uses https, the owner will see the domain you visited, as it can see the dns requests (like www.thesite.com, api.thesite.com). Also the owner might see some more details about what you were surfing on the site, for example if you browse a car related subreddit and the site loads ads from car manufacturers, or porn sites.

If the download was through https, the owner will know domain and mostly also the size of the file.

WPA2 will only make it harder for other users of the wifi to see your traffic, and people not knowing the wpa key (password). But all your internet traffic will go through the wifi router of the owner.

Comment: i see. sorry if i didn't make this clearer up there but the .pdf i opened is a document on my pc which i opened through browser so the link is something like file:///D:/New%20folder/as/New%20folder%20(8)/asdsd.pdf. so does this still means they know it? thank you in advance!

Comment: So edit your question.